# Simple encryption/decryption program using python (and tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, caesar-cipher

I am creating a simple program with a GUI to encrypt/decrypt text using different ciphers. I tried to make it so that it would be easy to add new ciphers.

This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk


ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


class Cipher:
    # encode_fun and decode_fun should take in args (key, message).
    def __init__(self, encode_fun, decode_fun):
        self.encode_fun = encode_fun
        self.decode_fun = decode_fun


        self.output = None

    def encode(self, key, message):
        try:
            self.output.delete(0, "end")
            self.output.insert(0, self.encode_fun(key, message))

        except:
            return

    def decode(self, key, message):
        try:
            self.output.delete(0, "end")
            self.output.insert(0, self.decode_fun(key, message))

        except:
            return

    def display(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        encode_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Encode")
        encode_button.pack(side="left")

        decode_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Decode")
        decode_button.pack(side="right")

        tk.Label(frame, text="Key:").pack()
        key_text_box = tk.Entry(frame)
        key_text_box.pack()

        tk.Label(frame, text="Text:").pack()
        message_text_box = tk.Entry(frame)
        message_text_box.pack()

        self.output = tk.Entry(frame, background="gray", foreground="white")
        self.output.pack()

        encode_button.config(command=
                lambda: self.encode(key_text_box.get(), message_text_box.get()))
        decode_button.config(command=
                lambda: self.decode(key_text_box.get(), message_text_box.get()))


def caesar_shift_encode(key, message):
    encoded_message = ""
    for char in message.lower():
        try:
            encoded_message += ALPHABET[(ALPHABET.index(char) + int(key)) % len(ALPHABET)]

        except:
            encoded_message += char

    return encoded_message


def caesar_shift_decode(key, message):
    return caesar_shift_encode(str(-int(key)), message)


def xor_cipher_encode(key, message):
    return "".join(
        [ALPHABET[ALPHABET.index(key_char) ^ ALPHABET.index(message_char)]
            for key_char, message_char in zip(key, message)]
    )


root = tk.Tk()

caesar_shift = Cipher(caesar_shift_encode, caesar_shift_decode)
caesar_shift.display(root)

xor_cipher = Cipher(xor_cipher_encode, xor_cipher_encode)
xor_cipher.display(root)

tk.mainloop()
```

GUI:
[image: what my GUI looks like]

I would be grateful to hear about any improvements that could be made to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

We don't like `from string import ascii_lowercase` ? Ok, whatever.

---

```
        self.output = None

    def encode(self, key, message):
        try:
            self.output.delete(0, "end")
```

I don't understand what's going on here.

Did we want to initialize `output` to the `[]` empty list, instead?

```
            self.output.insert(0, self.encode_fun(key, message))
```

Note that inserting at front is O(N),
while appending at end is O(1).
Consider using a
[deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

[EDIT: Later we see `self.output = tk.Entry(frame, ...`.
Maybe the identifier `output` is on the vague side and
could be renamed to suggest that it's a display window?
Or maybe just a `# commment` here would help to
better communicate the intent.]

```
        except:
            return
```

No.

This should apparently mention `pass` instead of `return`,
though there's no difference in behavior ATM.
A `pass` emphasizes to the Gentle Reader that
we're evaluating this method for side effects.
If we *did* want `return` for some reason,
consider making it an explicit `return None`,
since that is what happens. Prefer `pass`,
consistent with the signature's (lack of) type hints.

Avoid "bare except".
Prefer `except Exception:`,
so as not to interfere with `KeyboardException`.
Better yet, use `except AttributeError:` if
that's what you're expecting,
and fix the code defect which triggers "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'"
if that's what motivated the `try`.

---

Kudos on keeping the Tk graphic calls confined to `.display()`.
For one thing, this makes it easy to add
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
later on for encode / decode.

I also appreciate how everything is a local variable
rather than defining `self.this`, `self.that`, and `self.the_other`.
It reduces coupling, and means the Reader has fewer
things to worry about when reading other bits of code.

---

Please add these type hints:

```
def caesar_shift_encode(key: str, message: str) -> str:
```

I initially expected `key: int`, based on the
usual definition of a Caesar cipher.

```
        except:
            encoded_message += char
```

No.

Here, at least, it is apparent that Author's Intent was
to cope with "ValueError: substring not found".
So say that explicitly.
In any event, don't use a bare `except`.

---

```
def xor_cipher_encode(key, message):
```

This is an odd signature.
It suggests parallel structure with the Caesar signature
that accepted a single integer `f"{key}"`.
But it's not that.

In a crypto context we might expect 128 bits or 512 bits
of high-entropy keying material.
But it's not that.

It turns out the "key" is a "one-time pad". Ok.
I'm just surprised is all.

Validate that len(otp) >= len(message),
so caller won't be surprised by silent truncation.

---

```
root = tk.Tk() ...
```

Please protect this with a guard:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() ...
```

Why?

At some point you or a collaborator will want to
write a unit test,
which should be able to `import` this
without side effects.

---

This program accomplishes its design goals,
with fairly clear and mostly bug free code.

I would be happy to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks on this codebase.

Comment: `self.output` is an instance of `tk.Entry`. (I need to access it to display the encrypted/decrypted message. And `self.output.delete(0, "end")` clears the entry so that `self.output.insert(0, ...)` can insert the encrypted/decrypted text in (to replace the previous text).